# Java 11 ClassPathResource loading slower than with java 8

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-11

I have an application that loads the i18n during runtime and noticed that the same code with java 8 loads a lot faster, taking even up to 6 times more time.

The loading is truly simple
`return new ClassPathResource(resource, plugin.getClassLoader());`

The class loader is a ChildFirstClassLoader which extends URLClassLoader.

I have been doing research to see if there was any impact due to the module and classloader changes, but cannot find the cause.

The application itself looks to run slower with any jdk > 8. I have tried with 9, 11, 13 and 17, and they all have that same time consumed loading resources that was not before.

What could be causing this?
Edit: Adding the childfirst classloader and a link to the [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html).

```
public class ChildFirstClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public ChildFirstClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(urls, parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // has the class loaded already?
        Class<?> loadedClass = findLoadedClass(name);
        if (loadedClass == null) {
            try {
                // find the class from given jar urls 
                loadedClass = findClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // Hmmm... class does not exist in the given urls.
                // Let's try finding it in our parent classloader.
                // this'll throw ClassNotFoundException in failure.  
                loadedClass = super.loadClass(name, resolve);
            }
        }

        if (resolve) {      // marked to resolve
            resolveClass(loadedClass);
        }
        return loadedClass;
    }
```

Comment: Neither `ClassPathResource` nor `ChildFirstClassLoader` seem to be standard classes, so you can’t expect strangers on the internet to know more about them than you, without specifying any context. If your i18n loading includes `PropertyResourceBundle`, be aware that it tries to load as UTF-8 now and only when this fails, it will fall back to the old ISO-LATIN-1 behavior. This may take some time.

Comment: You are right, ClassPathResource is part of Spring framework. Will update the question with a link there. ChildFirstClassLoader.. will add that into the question as well. And check out the encoding.